# ng-repeat para array de imagenes

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

tengo una funcion que llama al elemento 'categorias' de la BD.
Esta tabla 'Categorias' tiene un campo llamado 'galeria' que es un array de imagenes. Quiero hacer un ng-repeat que me muestre las imagenes de este campo. el código que tengo, pero que no funciona, es este:

```
<div class="col-md-3"
          ng-repeat="c in Categorias">
          <div class="img">
              <img ng-src="{{asset('img/galeria/[[c.galeria]')}}" alt="">
          </div>
          </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas recorriendo *Categorias*, esta, contiene un arreglo de objetos que se llama *Galeria* y esta, objetos con la propiedad `img`, recorrelo asi :

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="c in Categorias">
  <div class="img" ng-repeat="galeria in c.galeria">
   <img ng-src="{{galeria.img}}">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionó! gracias

Comment: Me alegro, saludos! @RonelJimenez

Answer (score 0):

si mal no entiendo, tu estas iterando el array **Categorias** pero tus imagenes estan en el array **Galeria**

Verifica si estas recorriendo el array correcto y si los valores te estan llegando tal como lo tienes (puedes hacerlo por medio de etiquetas **HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="c in Categorias">
 <div class="img">
  <p>{{c.galeria}} </p>
 </div>
</div>
```